# How to properly expose C++ API using interfaces including derived interfaces?

Tags: c++, interface, casting

The code below illustrates the issue. I am trying to create an API for a C++ component using only interfaces (C++ virtual classes). I have a Base and Derived class and have corresponding IBase and IDerived interfaces but this leads to an error when I try to cast IBase to Derived. 
 error C2594: 'type cast' : ambiguous conversions from 'IBase *' to 'Derived *'

It seems a reasonable thing I am trying to do which Java or C# wouldn't bat an eyelid at. Is there a way of achieving something like this in C++

```
class IBase
{
public :
  virtual int method_A(void) = 0;
  virtual int method_B(void) = 0;
  virtual int method_C(void) = 0;
};

class IDerived : public IBase
{
public :
  virtual int method_D(void) = 0;
};

class Base : public IBase
{
  int method_A(void) {return 1;};
  int method_B(void) {return 2;};
  int method_C(void) {return 3;};
};

class Derived : public IDerived, private Base
{
public:
  int method_D(void) {return 4;};
};

class HandleDerived
{
public :
  int handle_base(IBase * i_base)
  {
    Derived * derived = (Derived *) i_base;
    return derived->method_D();
  }
};
```

Comment: Use virtual inheritance

Comment: ...and don't use C style casts. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is multiple inheritance. Your `Derived` is derived from:

- `IDerived`, which is derived from `IBase`
- `Base`, which is *also* derived from `IBase`

So, when you want to handle an `IBase` pointer like a `Derived` pointer in your function `handle_base()`, it is not clear which `IBase` you are referring to: The one from `IDerived`, or the one from `Base`.

The solution could be to use `public virtual` inheritance. However, you should probably check out the [C++ FQA Light](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/inheritance-multiple.html) on the matter.

Your remark regarding "Java or C# wouldn't bat an eyelid" at this isn't quite on the mark. Even a pure virtual base class in C++ is still a *class*, not an interface (in the Java sense of the word), i.e. you still have a case of multiple inheritance. Java's solution is to differentiate between a class and an interface; (one of) C++'s solution is virtual inheritance.